# How to only get id from params in select form to redirect to user show page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

controller:

```
class CandidatesController < ApplicationController
  helper_method :current_or_guest_user
  def show
    # authorize! :read, @user
    @candidate = Candidate.friendly.find(params[:id])
    @candidates = Candidate.all
    if request.path != candidate_path(@candidate)
      redirect_to @candidate, notice: 'moved permanently'
    end
    @comparison = UserComparisonService.new(current_user, @candidate) if current_user
    @contact = ContactCandidate.new(candidate_email: @candidate.email)
  end

  def send_unregistered
    @candidate = Candidate.find(params[:id])
    if @candidate.send_unregistered(params[:contact_candidate])
      flash[:error] = nil
      flash[:notice] = "You have emailed #{@candidate.full_name} an invitation to Votus"
    else
      flash[:error] = "Your invitation could not send."
    end
    redirect_to candidate_path(@candidate)
  end
end
```

select form in view:

```
      - if current_user
        = form_tag candidate_path(:id), :method => :get do
          = select_tag :id, options_from_collection_for_select(@candidates, :slug, :full_name), :style => "width:100%; margin-left: 3px;"
          = submit_tag 'Go'
```

---

So from my code above, the select form takes me to `http://localhost:3000/candidates/id?utf8=%E2%9C%93&id=75f90119-a071-470e-90cd-c04edfe02339&commit=Go`

However, I need :

```
http://localhost:3000/candidates/75f90119-a071-470e-90cd-c04edfe02339
```

to get to the correct route.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it looks like this

`candidate_path(:id)`

should be given the `@candidate` instead of id.

`candidate_path(@candidate)`